intl-tel-input hide search field
I tried
countrySearch: false but the search bar is still there. I recently updated from v17 to v23.0.11 and the Search bar is not expected.
Anyone can help me? Thanks!
I tried the following options to the IntlTelInput options
countrySearch: false
searchCountryFlag: false
